# Newbie to iPhone SDK. How can I insert text into a UILabel without 'setText'...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Okay, so I have a basic application and I built a custom numeric keyboard using some buttons. I have a button, for example 1, and a UILabel above. I got it to where when you click the button 1, it sets the text of the label to 1. Pretty simple stuff. But I need to add multiple characters and it's not letting me do so. Something like addText or insertText but addText isn't even a Cocoa method and insertText isn't what I'm looking for. Any help? Sorry for the newbie question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If what you’re looking for is a way to append a character to the end of the label’s string, do something like this:

```
[myLabel setText:[[myLabel text] stringByAppendingString:@"1"]];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. Now this is a little trickier but the UIField is a price, and I want to automatically add a decimal place the the field as the number increments it's value. For example, when I type '1' the field would be something like 0.01, then if I hit '2' it'd be 0.12, then if I hit three it would look like 1.23. Any ideas? Thanks for your fast help! :)

Comment: Alex, this sounds like a separate query and you would quite likely get better responses posting it as a new question

Comment: Separate question really but, I asked this question 2 years ago and there are quite a few approaches: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593230/struggling-with-currency-in-cocoa>

Answer (score 1):

A UILabel's text property is an NSString.  You should look over the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to see what all is possible.  The methods `stringByAppendingString`, `stringByAppendingFormat`, and `stringWithFormat` look like they might be useful for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff Kelley [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812732/newbie-to-iphone-sdk-how-can-i-insert-text-into-a-uilabel-without-settext/4812753#4812753) your question about appending text to a `UILabel`. With regards to your follow-up comment about the price:

If the user is entering numeric values into a `UITextField`, the delegate should respond to the `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method. An example of what you might do is:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fmt setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];

    NSDecimalNumber *newCentValue = [[fmt numberFromString:string] decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:-2];
    // "price" is an instance, global, static, whatever.. NSDecimalNumber object
    NSDecimalNumber *newPrice = [[price decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:1] decimalNumberByAdding:newCentValue];

    NSString *labelText = [fmt stringFromNumber:newPrice];
    // do something with new label
}
```

Note that this method does not deal with the user wanting to *remove* a digit, etc.