# NSNumberFormatter, NSDecimalNumber and Scientific Notation

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

I'm having a serious dispute with NSNumberFormatter, and even after going through its extensive documentation, I haven't quite been able to wrap my head around a pretty straightforward issue that I encountered. I hope you guys can help me out.

What I have: an `NSDecimalNumber` representing a calculation result, displayed in a `UITextField`
What I need: Scientific notation of that result.

What I'm doing:

```
-(void)setScientificNotationForTextField:(UITextField*)tf Text:(NSString*)text {

NSString* textBefore = text;

// use scientific notation, i.e. NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
//[formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
NSDecimalNumber* number = (NSDecimalNumber*)[formatter numberFromString:text];
tf.text = [number descriptionWithLocale:[[Utilities sharedUtilities] USLocale]];

NSString* textAfter = tf.text;
// DEBUG
NSLog(@"setScientificNotation | text before = %@, text after = %@", textBefore, textAfter);

[formatter release];
}
```

What happens:
A certain result may be 0.0099. `textBefore` will hold that correct value. If I don't tell the formatter to generate decimal numbers (commented out in the above snippet), it will create an NSNumber from an NSDecimalNumber which creates a false result and turns `textAfter`into 0.009900000000000001 - a rounding error due to the reduced precision of NSNumber over NSDecimalNumber. 
If I do tell the NumberFormatter to generate decimals, it will still create the wrong result . And what's more, where before it would insert the exponent notation (e.g. "1.23456e-10"), it would now generate (and thus display) the full decimal number, which is not what I want.

Again, I'd like to have the formatter use NSDecimalNumber so it doesn't falsify results plus have exponent notation where necessary.

Am I using the class wrong? Did I misinterpret the documentation? Can someone explain why this happens and how I can create the behavior I want? I will of course continue researching and update if I find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just cast an `NSNumber` to an `NSDecimalNumber` and expect it to work. If your number is not too complex, you can ditch `NSNumberFormatter` and try using this instead:

```
NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:text];
```

That will give you an actual `NSDecimalNumber` instance, with its precision.

Unfortunately, `setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:` doesn't work properly. It's a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317311/obtaining-an-nsdecimalnumber-from-a-locale-specific-string).
If your number is too complex to work with `decimalNumberWithString:`, you're probably out of luck with Apple's APIs. Your only options are either parsing the string manually into something `NSDecimalNumber` can understand or performing some post-processing on the imprecise value given to you by `NSNumberFormatter`.

Finally, if you really want a number in scientific notation, why not just use the number formatter you just used? Just call `stringFromNumber:` to get the formatted value.

Comment: It's true (and I realized after looking over your first version of the above answer) that I should've used stringFromNumber with the NSDecimalNumber I get from the text instead of numberFromString. I'm formatting strings depending on their length now: if too long to fit into the text field, I'm applying the scientific notation. It's not working 100% right now, but I think it's taking shape. Thanks for your answer and the link; I was sort of hoping it'd be a bug ^^