# NSDecimalNumber appear NaN

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdecimalnumber

When save `NSDecimalNumber` in `EditViewController`, in `DisplayTableViewController` value appear `NaN`

Please need advice to solve this issue. Thanks

My code:

```
- (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender {
    editGift.nameOfGift = nameTextField.text;
    editGift.priceOfGift = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:priceTextField.text];

    AppDelegate *myApp = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [myApp saveContext];
    [self.delegate editGiftViewControllerDidSave:self];
}
```

[Please watch video explanation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGFEmZrIECc)

Input value:

```
currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init]; 

[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

 personGift.priceOfGift = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:priceTextField.text];
```

Comment: What's the input value, i.e. what is `priceTextField.text`?

Comment: input value:     currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    personGift.priceOfGift = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:priceTextField.text];

Comment: ur input value is not formatted to the NSDecimalNumber thus giving NaN. check the input! Log the textfield value before putting it in the NSDecimalNumber and post it;)

Comment: I meant what is the value of `pricefield.Text`, not what is some other code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is unclear about when it applies the currency formatting, but given your video it is very likely that the value of the text field is "$6,000". That is not a number (thus "NaN").

Comment: I believe what Rob here is saying is what causes your problem. As your getting the text value which includes the '$'-sign. Remove your $-sign from `priceTextField.text` when the user clicks save. Just as a heads up. You could also check for invalid numbers. like '1.2.3.4..00'

Comment: Thank you very much Rob and Christer, How i can remove $-sign from textfield?

Comment: You already have a currency number formatter handy. Use numberFromString: to convert the text into an `NSNumber`. Ideally, you should use `setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:` so that you get a decimal number out. There used to be a bug that prevented that from working as easily as you'd like, but hopefully by now it's fixed (it's been years). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317311/obtaining-an-nsdecimalnumber-from-a-locale-specific-string

Answer (score 2):

**NSDecimalNumber** documentation says:

> Besides digits, numericString can include an initial “+” or “–”; a single “E” or “e”, to indicate the exponent of a number in scientific notation; and a single NSDecimalSeparator to divide the fractional from the integral part of the number.

You have to verify that the string in `priceTextField.text` contains only **valid characters** - and in valid order. One thing to check especially is whether you have decimal point or decimal comma, depending on user locale. Therefore you might want to consider using:

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString
locale:(NSDictionary *)locale
```