# Making NSDecimalNumber Codable

Tags: swift, swift4

Is it possible to extend `NSDecimalNumber` to conform `Encodable & Decodable` protocols?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your requirements? What are you trying to encode / decode?

Comment: @LorenzoB I checked Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types for encoding and decoding custom types. I'm trying to parse responses from server which I'd loose precision if I used Double.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to extend `NSDecimalNumber` to conform to `Encodable` & `Decodable` protocols. Jordan Rose explains it in the following [swift evolution email thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/swift-evolution@swift.org/msg28112.html).

If you need `NSDecimalValue` type in your API you can build computed property around `Decimal`.

```
struct YourType: Codable {
    var decimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber {
        get { return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: decimalValue) }
        set { decimalValue = newValue.decimalValue }
    }
    private var decimalValue: Decimal
}
```

Btw. If you are using `NSNumberFormatter` for parsing, beware of a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317311/obtaining-an-nsdecimalnumber-from-a-locale-specific-string) that causes precision loss in some cases.

```
let f = NumberFormatter()
f.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
f.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let z = f.number(from: "8.3")!
// z.decimalValue._exponent is not -1
// z.decimalValue._mantissa is not (83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Parse strings this way instead:

```
NSDecimalNumber(string: "8.3", locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX"))
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift you should use [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) type. This type confirms to protocols `Encodable & Decodable` from the box.

If you have `NSDecimalNumber` type in your code it's easy to cast it to `Decimal`

```
let objcDecimal = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 10)
let swiftDecimal = (objcDecimal as Decimal)
```

Answer (score 2):

With **Swift 5.1** you can use property wrappers to avoid the boilerplate of writing a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` / `encode(to encoder: Encoder)`.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct NumberString {
    private let value: String
    var wrappedValue: NSDecimalNumber

    init(wrappedValue: NSDecimalNumber) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        value = wrappedValue.stringValue
    }
}

extension NumberString: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        value = try String(from: decoder)
        wrappedValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: value)
    }
}

extension NumberString: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(wrappedValue.stringValue)
    }
}

extension NumberString: Equatable {}
```

Usage:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    @NumberString var value: NSDecimalNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, We are maintaining legacy code which is **Objective-C** and **Swift**
One of the modules we needed to have a property of type NSNumber (internal API reason) which is not supported by Codable
So We use Codable for almost all supported data types and NSCoding with a help of NSKeyedUnarchiver for unsupported types

> I am sharing here a sample of the code, as a reference that might help
> someone who has a such scenario.

```
class Branch: NSObject, Codable {

    @objc var discountMaxLimit: NSNumber?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case discountInfoKeys
    }

    private enum CorporateDiscountInfoKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case discountMaxLimit = "discount_max_limit"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
         var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         var discountInfoK = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: discountInfoKeys.self, forKey: .discountInfoKeys)
         if let value = discountMaxLimit {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            try discountInfoK.encode(data, forKey: .discountMaxLimit)
          }
     }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let discountInfo = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: discountInfoKeys.self, forKey: .discountInfoKeys)
        let discountMaxLimitData = try discountInfo.decode(Data.self, forKey: .discountMaxLimit)
        discountMaxLimit = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(discountMaxLimitData) as? NSNumber
    }

}
```