# How would I decode a NSDecimalNumber without loss of precision?

Tags: swift, codable, nsdecimalnumber, jsondecoder

is there any way to tell JSONDecoder to convert incoming decimals to
Strings?

```
 public struct Transaction: Decodable
 {
    public let total: NSDecimalNumber?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case total = "AMOUNT"

    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let total = try values.decode(Decimal.self, forKey: .total)
        self.total = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: total);
    }

 }
```

Consider what would happen when AMOUNT is something like 397289527598234759823475455622342424358363514.42

I suppose with the code that I have I'd get nonConformingFloatDecodingStrategy exception with no recourse to recover from that 
or loss of precision.

Struggles around idiotic swift Decimal are documented all over the s.o.
in particular here:

[Making NSDecimalNumber Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294765/making-nsdecimalnumber-codable)

Comment: You gotta have it as `String` in your `JSON` to begin with, otherwise it gonna covert it to `Double` first, and then to your type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997953/2303865

Comment: yes @LeoDabus, that's useful only for case when you both encode and decode values yourself and totally useful for data from remote system you have no control over

Comment: @AntonTropashko try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131900/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `JSONDecoder` is just a wrapper around `JSONSerialization`, which decodes decimal numbers into `Double` internally and only after converts them to `Decimal`. Sadly, unless you create your own JSON decoder, you cannot get around this issue when using numeric decimals from JSON.

The only workaround currently possible is to change your backend to send all decimal numbers as `String`s and then convert those into `Decimal`s after decoding them as `String`s.

For more information, have a look at this open Swift bug: [SR-7054](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7054).