# I am writing the code using OOPS concept, but am getting the error regarding private access specifier although i am accessing it within the class

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, private

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class player{
  private:
    string name;
    int health;
    int xp;
 public:
 void names (string get_name, int get_health, int get_xp){
     name=get_name;
     health=get_health;
     xp=get_xp;
 }
    
    
};
int main(){
    player p;
    p.names("Mohit",100,3);
    cout<<p.health<<endl;
    cout<<p.xp<<endl;
    cout<<p.name<<endl;
    player *hero = new player();
    hero ->names("Tavishi",1000,3);
    cout<<(*hero).name<<endl;
    cout<<(*hero).xp<<endl;
    cout<<(*hero).health<<endl;
      delete hero;
    return 0;

}
```

I am accessing the attributes within the class only, then why am I getting the error regarding the private access specifier??

Comment: With this `p.health` or `p.xp` etc. you try to access the private class members directly.

Comment: `main` is not within the class.

Comment: [What does it mean to be a private member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213279/what-does-it-mean-to-be-a-private-member-c-classes)

Comment: In this case it's clear that the problem is that you're trying to access the class member from outside the class, but you should've specified what error you're getting so the question is clearer

Comment: Not sure this question needs to be closed. It looks like a reproducible problem. Certainly I think I can see the problem from the code, well enough to assess the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your code, fixed up a bit:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // Include what you use

class player {
 private:
  std::string name;
  int health;
  int xp;

 public:
  void names(std::string get_name, int get_health, int get_xp) {
    name = get_name;
    health = get_health;
    xp = get_xp;
  }

  // Simplest fix: Getters
  std::string get_name() const { return name; }
  int get_health() const { return health; }
  int get_xp() const { return xp; }
};
int main() {
  player p;
  p.names("Mohit", 100, 3);
  // cout<<p.health<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  // cout<<p.xp<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  // cout<<p.name<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  std::cout << p.get_health() << '\n'
            << p.get_xp() << '\n'
            << p.get_name() << '\n';
  player *hero = new player();
  hero->names("Tavishi", 1000, 3);
  std::cout << hero->get_name() << '\n';  // Prefer arrow operator over (*).
  std::cout << hero->get_xp() << '\n';
  std::cout << hero->get_health() << '\n';
  delete hero;
  return 0;
}
```

You were using an object in the `main()` function, which is **not** "within the class" to attempt to access private members. When people say that you can use private members directly "within the class" they mean from within a class member function. Anything else is considered "out of the class" and the private/public restrictions are enforced.

If you need access to them, you can provide *getter* functions in your class, which is what I did.

Here's your code again, this time better utilizing C++. Namely, constructors and operator overloading.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>  // Include what you use

class player {
 private:
  std::string name{};  // Default member initialization makes default ctor
  int health = 0;      // easy to implement
  int xp = 0;

 public:
  // Provide constructors for easier initialization
  player() = default;
  player(std::string name, int health, int xp)
      : name(name), health(health), xp(xp) {}

  //   void names(std::string get_name, int get_health, int get_xp) {
  //     name = get_name;
  //     health = get_health;
  //     xp = get_xp;
  //   }

  // Simplest fix: Getters
  // ** Getter may not be necessary anymore if your only purpose is printing
  std::string get_name() const { return name; }
  int get_health() const { return health; }
  int get_xp() const { return xp; }

  // If you want to cout object directly, provide operator<<()
  // Friends can access private members directly; they are **not** class members
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const player& p) {
    return sout << p.health << '\n' << p.xp << '\n' << p.name << '\n';
  }
};
int main() {
  player p{"Mohit", 100, 3};  // Much simpler initialization
  // cout<<p.health<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  // cout<<p.xp<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  // cout<<p.name<<endl;  // Not "within the class"
  std::cout << p;  // Simpler way to print
  auto hero =
      std::make_unique<player>("Tavishi", 1000, 3);  // Smart pointer
                                                     // no need to delete
  std::cout << *hero;
  return 0;
}
```