# Functional dependent attribute in c++ class/struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, attributes, functional-dependencies

I want to make a class/struct where one of the attributes is functionally dependent on other attributes. How can this be achieved?

```cpp
struct Numbers {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c; // c == a+b
}


Numbers n1 {1, 2, 3}; // Ok.
Numbers n2 {1, 2, 4}; // Error!
```

In my use case, `a, b, c` are constant, if that matters (so `const int` may be used).

All attributes will appear many times in class/struct methods, so the goal is to cache the value `a+b`. Addition is used as an example, the dependency function may be more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are mutable then you can't enforce that `c` is kept in sync; all three would have to be const for you to enforce this invariant.

The simplest approach would be to make `c` a function:

```
struct Numbers {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c() const { return a + b; }
}
```

If you want the value of `c` to be cached instead of computed when needed then you need to hide `a` and `b` behind accessors as well so that you can update `c` when they are updated.

```
class Numbers {
public:
  Numbers(int a, int b) : ma{a}, mb{b} { updateC(); }

  int a() const { return ma; }
  int b() const { return mb; }
  int c() const { return mc; }

  void a(int v) { ma = v; updateC(); }
  void b(int v) { mb = v; updateC(); }
  // No setter for c

private:
  void updateC() { mc = ma + mb; }

  int ma;
  int mb;
  int mc;
};
```

Comment: OP said the members don't need to be mutable, so no need for the setters - but if you have them they shouldn't have the same names as getters.

Comment: *"but if you have them they shouldn't have the same names as getters"* -- I disagree on this point. They have an obviously-different call signature. I don't know anyone who would be confused by this interface.

Comment: In fact, this approach is [_explicitly recommended_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760877/501250) by some.

Comment: Some, but not many. The name of a function should describe what the function does. You can't see the signature at the callsite.

Comment: If the name is descriptive then this isn't a problem. Is `foo.height(42);` really that opaque?

Comment: Yes, it is. Use verbs. Describing words. This is wisdom that's been available for decades

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. This isn't really the right venue for an extended discussion of style.

Comment: Indeed, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
struct Numbers {
    Numbers(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b), c(a + b) {}

private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c; // c == a+b
};
```

Edit:
To keep the values of `a` and `b` updated, and to get the values of those variables, you'll have to use get & set methods, like in @cdhowie response.

Comment: Don't forget accessors.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I took them as obvious, and cdhowiealready mentioned them in his response, but you are right.