# Not able to set getters and setters in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to set getters and setters for  an array- I am trying to right click on the  variable to find an option to refactor it ( there seems no such option).I also tried to type in the "code editor" but none seem to be working. Can I please be helped?

Comment: Like you said, "there seems to be no such option"..

Comment: @user - You might 1) Consider why there are very few getters and setters in the C++ standard library 2) Read [Are get and set functions popular with C++ programmers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737409/are-get-and-set-functions-popular-with-c-programmers?lq=1)

Comment: [Pseudo-Classes and Quasi-Classes Confuse Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This does not work for C++ projects in VS2010, it only works for C# projects.

Comment: Yeah, you have to write them yourself.

Comment: along side I also wanted to know if we could have setters and  getters for a CStringArray?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying you want to be able to get and set the underlying `char*`? If so then you can use the `Add()` function to a default constructed CStringArray to add data to it. To get the data use the `GetData()` function. See [CStringArray documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aaaacss(v=vs.80).aspx) for more info.