# How to show original value from MySQL database to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning!

Hi, i have problem to show data value from "Medium Text" field in MySQL.

> data in my database: 119.511865
>
> result on php: 119.51186499999999

How to show data on database same with result on php?

[UPDATE]
here my data on field coordinates:

> 119.5206,-5.071414,0.0 119.52059600000001,-5.071347,0.0 119.52062600000001,-5.071106000000001,0.0 119.520632,-5.071052,0.0 119.520711,-5.070732,0.0 119.52071299999999,-5.070723,0.0 119.52271800000001,-5.070708,0.0 119.523891,-5.070702,0.0 119.523942,-5.070702000000001,0.0 119.524918,-5.0707,0.0 119.525947,-5.070687,0.0 119.52701800000001,-5.070678,0.0 119.52807499999999,-5.070671999999999,0.0 119.531112,-5.0706,0.0 119.531166,-5.070577,0.0 119.53105900000001,-5.070378999999999,0.0 119.53094500000002,-5.070183,0.0 119.53083,-5.069989,0.0 119.530716,-5.069795,0.0 119.53059400000001,-5.069605,0.0 119.530472,-5.069418,0.0 119.530342,-5.069234999999999,0.0 119.530205,-5.0690550000000005,0.0 119.53006,-5.068882,0.0 119.52990700000001,-5.068721999999999,0.0 119.52973200000001,-5.068572,0.0 119.529556,-5.068433,0.0 119.529373,-5.068300999999999,0.0 119.52919,-5.068173,0.0 119.529007,-5.068047,0.0 119.528824,-5.067916,0.0 119.528641,-5.067781,0.0 119.52846500000001,-5.067639,0.0 119.528305,-5.067486,0.0 119.52816,-5.067315,0.0 119.52812500000002,-5.067265,0.0 119.5281,-5.067196000000001,0.0 119.52803500000002,-5.066981,0.0 119.528013,-5.066659,0.0 119.52799000000002,-5.066337,0.0 119.528031,-5.066015,0.0 119.527955,-5.065704000000001,0.0 119.52789,-5.065403,0.0 119.527803,-5.065081,0.0 119.52769400000001,-5.064759,0.0 119.527608,-5.064686,0.0 119.52757999999999,-5.064484000000001,0.0 119.527317,-5.064455999999999,0.0 119.527007,-5.064268,0.0 119.52668499999999,-5.064097,0.0 119.526278,-5.06397,0.0 119.525677,-5.063908,0.0 119.52537800000002,-5.063952,0.0 119.52509900000001,-5.064017999999999,0.0 119.52477899999998,-5.064126000000001,0.0 119.52452099999998,-5.064127,0.0 119.524093,-5.064129000000001,0.0 119.52279600000001,-5.063951,0.0 119.52249600000002,-5.063844999999999,0.0 119.522153,-5.0637609999999995,0.0 119.521467,-5.063742000000001,0.0 119.52110300000001,-5.063743,0.0 119.520417,-5.063746,0.0 119.51988199999998,-5.063769,0.0 119.51951799999999,-5.063728,0.0 119.519003,-5.063623,0.0 119.518574,-5.063431,0.0 119.51808000000001,-5.063218000000001,0.0 119.517651,-5.063069,0.0 119.517351,-5.063006000000001,0.0 119.51711599999999,-5.063028,0.0 119.51677300000001,-5.063137,0.0 119.51643100000001,-5.063224,0.0 119.51603400000002,-5.063108,0.0 119.51564800000001,-5.063066,0.0 119.515348,-5.062939,0.0 119.51502599999999,-5.062875,0.0 119.51453400000001,-5.062920000000001,0.0 119.514106,-5.063029,0.0 119.513571,-5.063203000000001,0.0 119.51329300000002,-5.063462,0.0 119.513037,-5.063764000000001,0.0 119.512824,-5.0640220000000005,0.0 119.512697,-5.064366999999999,0.0 119.512613,-5.064732,0.0 119.512593,-5.065205000000001,0.0 119.51257300000002,-5.065699,0.0 119.512554,-5.066279,0.0 119.512299,-5.066796,0.0 119.51217100000001,-5.066968000000001,0.0 119.51197900000001,-5.067162000000001,0.0 119.51163700000001,-5.067314,0.0 119.511209,-5.067487,0.0 119.510888,-5.067552999999999,0.0 119.51046000000001,-5.067727,0.0 119.50984,-5.067900999999999,0.0 119.508311,-5.068541,0.0 119.50784,-5.068714,0.0 119.507567,-5.068777999999999,0.0 119.507431,-5.068737,0.0 119.507287,-5.068689,0.0 119.50715399999999,-5.0687169999999995,0.0 119.506747,-5.068675000000001,0.0 119.50642500000001,-5.068591,0.0 119.506168,-5.068440999999999,0.0 119.50606000000002,-5.068263,0.0 119.506032,-5.068256,0.0 119.505909,-5.068034,0.0 119.50580200000002,-5.06797,0.0 119.505566,-5.067821,0.0 119.50533,-5.067714,0.0 119.50481500000001,-5.067652000000001,0.0 119.504408,-5.067610000000001,0.0 119.50387200000002,-5.067548,0.0 119.503486,-5.06755,0.0 119.503187,-5.067572,0.0 119.50295099999998,-5.067659,0.0 119.50287900000001,-5.067718,0.0 119.50273700000001,-5.067746,0.0 119.502438,-5.067853999999999,0.0 119.502139,-5.06807,0.0 119.50162600000002,-5.068309,0.0 119.50115500000001,-5.068547,0.0 119.500663,-5.068785000000001,0.0 119.50029999999998,-5.068894,0.0 119.49988200000001,-5.068948999999999,0.0 119.499196,-5.068823,0.0 119.498703,-5.068653000000001,0.0 119.49838100000001,-5.068547,0.0 119.49777999999999,-5.0683560000000005,0.0 119.497451,-5.0682100000000005,0.0 119.497458,-5.06828,0.0 119.497491,-5.06875,0.0 119.49746200000001,-5.069502,0.0 119.49740200000001,-5.069973,0.0 119.49734100000002,-5.070474000000001,0.0 119.49734199999999,-5.070725,0.0 119.497343,-5.071039,0.0 119.49731400000002,-5.071445999999999,0.0 119.49730000000001,-5.071916,0.0 119.497394,-5.072104000000001,0.0 119.49755200000001,-5.072386,0.0 119.49767800000001,-5.072698999999999,0.0 119.497866,-5.072792,0.0 119.498116,-5.072854000000001,0.0 119.498304,-5.072947,0.0 119.49855500000001,-5.073197,0.0 119.49877499999998,-5.073541,0.0 119.49883900000002,-5.073822,0.0 119.49892199999998,-5.074071,0.0 119.498934,-5.074103999999999,0.0 119.498935,-5.074355,0.0 119.498905,-5.074699999999999,0.0 119.49881300000001,-5.07517,0.0 119.498845,-5.075546,0.0 119.49894,-5.075797,0.0 119.499066,-5.076016,0.0 119.499318,-5.076453000000001,0.0 119.499349,-5.076547,0.0 119.499319,-5.076892000000001,0.0 119.49938699999998,-5.078271,0.0 119.499391,-5.079210999999999,0.0 119.499298,-5.079463,0.0 119.499361,-5.079588000000001,0.0 119.49958100000002,-5.079869000000001,0.0 119.499801,-5.080244,0.0 119.49989600000002,-5.080432,0.0 119.49995900000002,-5.080714,0.0 119.50002300000001,-5.080902,0.0 119.50002300000001,-5.080993999999999,0.0 119.502111,-5.081472,0.0 119.503832,-5.082776,0.0 119.50511400000002,-5.083742,0.0 119.505703,-5.084187,0.0 119.505715,-5.084095,0.0 119.506043,-5.083532999999999,0.0 119.506293,-5.083207999999999,0.0 119.507215,-5.081518,0.0 119.50750800000002,-5.081272,0.0 119.50835799999999,-5.07946,0.0 119.50969699999999,-5.077704,0.0 119.50996499999998,-5.077447,0.0 119.510361,-5.077155,0.0 119.51161899999998,-5.076447000000001,0.0 119.51244,-5.07604,0.0 119.513844,-5.075267,0.0 119.51507499999998,-5.074615,0.0 119.516886,-5.073601,0.0 119.51747300000001,-5.073225,0.0 119.51961999999999,-5.071982,0.0 119.5206,-5.071414,0.0

Comment: Hello. What is the type of the field you tried to display ? float ? decimal ? how many digits ? And what is the request ? (any function as SUM/AVG/... used ?)

Comment: i use Medium Text on my field, exactly i store polygon data in this field.

Comment: I think it's not obvious from what you've shown here how the medium text in your database is getting converted to a float in PHP.

Comment: just need to show the original value from database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert float to string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876666/convert-float-to-string-in-php)

Comment: Please, provide the SQL request used to display the data :)
If you execute the request on phpmyadmin directly (for example) ... this is the same result as on your source code?

Comment: You can't, this is a memory limitation in all languages. Floating-point inaccuracy errors usually arise with floating-point arithmetic

Comment: PHP auto convert to float?

Comment: Right, well, some things are obviously happening in between that we can't see here. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @OverCoder have solution sir?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I was asking about PHP code too.

Comment: @Perumal93 i just use select query from laravel.

Comment: @MuhGhazaliAkbar What is the library you're using to interact with your SQL server? You need to find an option or something so it doesn't automatically convert float strings to actual floats. But, why are you using float numbers? Float numbers can never be actually accurate. Why are you not using `FLOAT` anyways?

Comment: @OverCoder If floats are not accurate, what else should be used? Like `double` or what? What way do you mean that?

Comment: @MuhGhazaliAkbar Each row in the database contains data like you posted in the question? or is it just the whole data from all the rows you posted?

Comment: @OverCoder what the data type of latitude and longtitude polygon? float? i use medium text

Comment: @OverCoder it just one row

Comment: One row has all those data that you posted in the question?

Comment: @MuhGhazaliAkbar I'm not entirely sure, `double` offers more accuracy up to something like 16 fractions, but you shouldn't rely on float/double accuracy for critical applications, especially when dealing with money. For dealing with Lon/Lat, I don't think the difference you're seeing is actually important, you can just reformat that number to limit the number of fractions up to 6 or something when output-ing, and you should be fine

Comment: @OverCoder What else would you suggest over `float` and `double`?

Comment: Interesting article for longitude/latitude mysql storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql : **Use MySQL's spatial extensions with GIS.** You have also some reflections with standard types

Comment: @Perumal93 [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) mentions `DOUBLE PRECISION(M, D)`, which I *think* would work

Comment: @Perumal93 [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11086776/2164304)

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my side.

## Via PhpMyAdmin / SQL

My request:

```
 SELECT id, value, AVG(value), SUM(value), value*1, value+1 FROM `41272408` GROUP BY id
```

The result:

[image: Structure]

[image: Result image]

It's working well :)

## Via PHP

### My code:

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT id, value, AVG(value), SUM(value), value*1, value+1 FROM `41272408` GROUP BY id';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

foreach( $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    echo implode(' ; ', $row);
    echo '<br />';

    echo 'with +1: ';
    echo implode(' ; ', array_map(function($v) { return $v + 1; }, $row));
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

### And the output:

```
1 ; 119.511865 ; 119.511865 ; 119.511865 ; 119.511865 ; 120.511865
with +1: 2 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 121.5118652 ;
---
119.51186499999999 ; 119.51186499999999 ; 119.51186499999999 ; 119.51186499999999 ; 120.51186499999999
with +1: 3 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 120.511865 ; 121.511865
```

As you can see, it's working well ... except for a PHP arithmetic operation (+1).

> Refers to PHP's documentation about **float** to find mode information: http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.float.php

Extract:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. [...]  Non elementary
>   arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error
>   propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. **If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.**

So, follow the documentation :) Use specific library for operations

## Other points

Interesting article for longitude/latitude MySql storage: [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)
**Use MySQL's spatial extensions with GIS.** You have also some reflections with standard types